# Finding the Largest Connected Blob Starting from Selected Point

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to extract a region from an image that is already marked with a certain color. In the picture below

[image]

I would like to extract only the pixels which belong to the sidewalk, that is, all pixels that belong to the black blob that is connected to the mid-lower part of the image. There are black dots outside that blob which I am not interested in. So if I could get roughly the region shown below

[image]

it would be perfect. Does anyone know of some common algorithms that can do this? Morphology? Region growing using a kind of flooding algorithm?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a starting point/seed inside that region? If yes, Region growing could be a possibility, as well as active contours class of algorithms, like Snakes or Level Sets. 

For all those methods you will have to define a criterion (or energy function for the active contours) which will make the contour stop at the limits you need. Since you're talking about a "black blob", a color-based criterion could be used, but it will not necessarily be very robust. 

For morphology have a look at the watershed operator. Again, the key will be in preprocessing the data ..

Comment: Yes I have a starting point, a small rectangle between x=150 and x=200, about 10 pixels high.

Comment: One solution could be to first extract all black pixels in the image, use morphological opening/closing to remove the small black parasite pixels, and then extract the largest black blob in the image. Using snakes is probably nice, since you can control the smoothness of the contour in the energy function (i.e. avoid growing your contour towards small remaining blows which would be connected to the main one).

Comment: http://iacl.ece.jhu.edu/Projects/gvf/snakedemo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that quite easily with a flood fill. If I use **ImageMagick** to demonstrate at the command line because it is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

So, bearing in mind that the pixel you identified as your seed is at around 440,520 in the image you supplied that includes the axes, we can floodfill all pixels that match that colour and touch the seed with cyan using:

```
convert scene.png -fill cyan -draw 'color 440,520 floodfill' result.png
```

[image]

Or, we can make a mask by changing the non-cyan pixels to white and the cyan pixels to black:

```
convert scene.png -fill cyan -draw 'color 440,520 floodfill' -fill white +opaque cyan -fill black -opaque cyan z.png
```

[image]

There are a thousand other things you can simply do from the command line to take this further... fill small holes in the mask, make a transparency layer from the mask - just ask more questions if you need a hand.

---

If you want to close the holes in your image, you probably want to use morphological functions. I am away from any computers with ImageMagick for a week so I can only tell you in general terms. Start with the pure black and white (no grey) picture above and try:

```
convert image.png -morphology open disk:3 result.jpg
```

Try replacing the word `open` above with `close`, `erode` or `dilate`. Experiment with `disk`, `disk:3` `disk:7` and so on.

Comment: Could you give an example for filling small holes? Thanks.

Comment: I have added some untested code as I am on the road for a while. It should give you an idea of how to fill holes.